# i can't see Code Snippet in ckeditor (django app)

Tags: javascript, django, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am developing a django application that directed me to a problem with ckeditor text editor
I can not see the Code Snippet

i have this config in setting.py

```
 CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {

'default': {
    'skin': 'moono',
    # 'skin': 'office2013',
    'toolbar_Basic': [
        ['Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic']
    ],
    'toolbar_YourCustomToolbarConfig': [

        {'name': 'document', 'items': ['Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates']},

        {'name': 'clipboard', 'items': ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo']},
        {'name': 'editing', 'items': ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll']},
        {'name': 'forms',
         'items': ['Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton',
                   'HiddenField']},
        '/',
        {'name': 'basicstyles',
         'items': ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat']},
        {'name': 'paragraph',
         'items': ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-',
                   'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl',
                   'Language']},
        {'name': 'links', 'items': ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor']},
        {'name': 'insert',
         'items': ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe', 'CodeSnippet']},
        '/',
        {'name': 'styles', 'items': ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize']},
        {'name': 'colors', 'items': ['TextColor', 'BGColor']},
        {'name': 'tools', 'items': ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks']},
        {'name': 'about', 'items': ['About']},

        '/',  # put this to force next toolbar on new line
        {'name': 'yourcustomtools', 'items': [
            # put the name of your editor.ui.addButton here
            'Preview',
            'Maximize',

        ]},

    ],


    'toolbar': 'YourCustomToolbarConfig',  # put selected toolbar config here
    # 'toolbarGroups': [{ 'name': 'document', 'groups': [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] }],

    # 'height': 291,
    # 'width': '100%',
    # 'filebrowserWindowHeight': 725,
    # 'filebrowserWindowWidth': 940,
    # 'toolbarCanCollapse': True,
    # 'mathJaxLib': '//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.2-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML',
    'tabSpaces': 4,
    'extraPlugins': ','.join([
        'uploadimage', # the upload image feature
        # your extra plugins here
        'div',
        'autolink',
        'autoembed',
        'embedsemantic',
        'autogrow',
        # 'devtools',
        'widget',
        'lineutils',
        'clipboard',
        'dialog',
        'dialogui',
        'elementspath'
    ]),


},
# my costum tool bar i created 
'special':  {
    'toolbar': 'Special',
    'toolbar_special': [
           ['codeSnippet', 'Youtube'],
    ],
    'extraPlugins': ','.join(['codeSnippet', 'youtube']),

}
}
```

**config.js**

```
/**
```

* @license Copyright (c) 2003-2018, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see https://ckeditor.com/legal/ckeditor-oss-license
 */

```
 CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
// Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
// config.language = 'fr';
// config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';

 CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
 ev.editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules( {
    elements : {
        img: function( el ) {
            // Add bootstrap "img-responsive" class to each inserted  image
            el.addClass('img-fluid');

            // Remove inline "height" and "width" styles and
            // replace them with their attribute counterparts.
            // This ensures that the 'img-responsive' class works
            var style = el.attributes.style;

            if (style) {
                // Get the width from the style.
                var match = /(?:^|\s)width\s*:\s*(\d+)px/i.exec(style),
                    width = match && match[1];

                // Get the height from the style.
                match = /(?:^|\s)height\s*:\s*(\d+)px/i.exec(style);
                var height = match && match[1];

                // Replace the width
                if (width) {
                    el.attributes.style =  el.attributes.style.replace(/(?:^|\s)width\s*:\s*(\d+)px;?/i, '');
                    el.attributes.width = width;
                }

                // Replace the height
                if (height) {
                    el.attributes.style = el.attributes.style.replace(/(?:^|\s)height\s*:\s*(\d+)px;?/i, '');
                    el.attributes.height = height;
                }
            }

            // Remove the style tag if it is empty
            if (!el.attributes.style)
                delete el.attributes.style;
        }
    }
 });
 });



CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
...
// Default language direction
 config.contentsLangDirection = 'rtl';
...
 };
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by uber you need to add extra pluggin, But I was confused with the format. Format will be like this:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'full',
        'extraPlugins': ','.join(
            [
                'codesnippet',
            ]),
    },
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me a way to not add full toolbar i.e. Default toolbar + codesnippet.

Comment: @RUGVED this code is doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the extra plugins to `toolbar_YourCustomToolbarConfig` block so thathey are displayed ie try adding this below

```
About
    {
                'name': 'extra',
                'items': [
                          'CodeSnippet', ],
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

the latest ckeditor 5.something plugins add be like this

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
'default': {
    'skin': 'moono',
    # 'skin': 'office2013',
    'toolbar_Basic': [
        ['Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic']
        
    ],
    'toolbar_YourCustomToolbarConfig': [
        {'name': 'document', 'items': ['Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates']},
        {'name': 'clipboard', 'items': ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo']},
        {'name': 'editing', 'items': ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll']},
        {'name': 'forms',
         'items': ['Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton',
                   'HiddenField']},
        '/',
        {'name': 'basicstyles',
         'items': ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat']},
        {'name': 'paragraph',
         'items': ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-',
                   'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl',
                   'Language']},
        {'name': 'links', 'items': ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor']},
        {'name': 'insert',
         'items': ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe']},
        '/',
        {'name': 'styles', 'items': ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize']},
        {'name': 'colors', 'items': ['TextColor', 'BGColor']},
        {'name': 'tools', 'items': ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks']},
        {'name': 'about', 'items': ['About']},

        '/',  # put this to force next toolbar on new line
        {'name': 'extra', 'items': [ 'CodeSnippet',
            # put the name of your editor.ui.addButton here
            'Preview',
            'Maximize',

        ]},
    ],
    'toolbar': 'YourCustomToolbarConfig',  # put selected toolbar config here
    # 'toolbarGroups': [{ 'name': 'document', 'groups': [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] }],
    # 'height': 291,
    # 'width': '100%',
    # 'filebrowserWindowHeight': 725,
    # 'filebrowserWindowWidth': 940,
    # 'toolbarCanCollapse': True,
    # 'mathJaxLib': '//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.2-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML',
    'tabSpaces': 4,
    'extraPlugins': ','.join([
        'uploadimage', # the upload image feature
        # your extra plugins here
        'div',
        'autolink',
        'autoembed',
        'embedsemantic',
        'autogrow',
        # 'devtools',
        'widget',
        'lineutils',
        'clipboard',
        'dialog',
        'dialogui',
        'elementspath',
        'codesnippet',
        'sourcedialog',
        'templates',
        'widget',
        'wsc',
        'sharedspace',
        'mathjax',
        'embedbase',
        'docprops',
        'magicline',
        'stylesheetparser',



    ]),
}
```

}**strong text**